# Return list web method

Tags: c#, wcf, webmethod

I have Web service and a method which makes a request to my table 'Customer' with Entity Framework.

I want to return the result of my request :

```
public List<Customer> MyMethod(int id)
{
    Model model = new Model();
    List<Customer> customer = new List<Customer>();

    try
    {
         customer = model.Customer.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         throw new System.NullReferenceException();
    }

    return customer;

}
```

In debug mode I have a list filled but when I call the method via SoapUI I have no answer.

Thank you

Comment: So in debug mode, this returns a filled `List<Customer>` but it doesn't work in normal mode, meaning it returns an empty `List<Customer>`?

Comment: No, the service returns nothing. I have an envelope of empty answer on SoapUI

Answer (score 1):

My full code :

Class Customer (generated by EF) :

```
[Table("Customer")]
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? Adress_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
}
```

Class Adress (generated by EF) :

```
[Table("Adress")]
public partial class Adress
{
    public Adress()
    {
        Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Adress")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Adress1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

My Web Method :

```
[WebMethod]
public Customer MyMethod(int id)
{
    Model model = new Model();
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    try
    {
        customer = model.Customer.Where(x => x.Name == id).First();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new System.NullReferenceException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }

    return customer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the following code:

```
public List<UserInfo> GetAllUserInfoDetailes()
        {
            List<UserInfo> user = new List<UserInfo>();
            using (Model1 pubs = new Model1())
            {
                var userId = (from p in pubs.TB_UserInfo select p);
                foreach (TB_UserInfo singleUser in userId)
                {
                    UserInfo a = new UserInfo();
                    a.EUserId = singleUser.User_Id;               
                    a.EUser_Name = singleUser.User_Name;
                    a.EAlias = singleUser.Alias;
                    a.EPassword = singleUser.Password;
                    a.EState = singleUser.State;
                    a.ECurrentPrevious = singleUser.CurrentPrevious;
                    a.EEmail = singleUser.Email;
                    a.EReportDutyTime = singleUser.ReportdutyTime;
                    a.ETeam_Id = singleUser.Team_Id;
                    a.ELogin_Time = DateTime.Now;
                    user.Add(a);
                }
            }
            return user;
        }
```

Then it can get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a virtual property in my class Customer which corresponds to another table (foreign key). If I remove this virtual property, I have a reponse but I want to return the joint

Answer (score 0):

Add WebMethod attribute to your method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Customer> MyMethod(int id)
{....}
```

Comment: I still haven't response. But if I remove the virtual property in my class, I have a response